# vim short for search replace with space in between

Tags: vim, replace, editor, vi

What is the vim short for this case?

```
A BCD_x 1.pdf A BCD_x 2.pdf
```

Desired output:

```
A BCD_x 1.pdf:::A BCD_x 2.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
:s/\s\(A\s\)/:::\1
```

Or how about this?

```
:s/\sA\@=/:::
```

Of course, as always with regexp search-and-replace everything depends on the particulars of your data. Of which you haven't given us much to work with.

Comment: Then use `%` before `s`, so that it reads `:%s/...`. The percent sign `%` makes it apply to the whole buffer. But *please* go read a decent regexp tutorial before all else, for example [`:h usr_27`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_27.html).